# Attached Event is not firing when I want to test my nuxt js project with jest

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, nuxt.js

I am building a web application with nuxt js + jest

My nuxt js component codes:

```js
export default {
  mounted () {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.eventClick)
  },
  destroyed () {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.eventClick)
  },
  methods: {
    eventClick () {
      console.log('click event triggered!')
    }
  }
}
```

My codes in jest:

```js
import Dashboard from '~/pages/admin/dashboard'

test('test click', () => {
    wrapper = mount(Dashboard)

    wrapper.trigger('click')
})
```

The problem is:
jest cannot fire click event and the code `console.log('click event triggered!')` is not executed.
How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event listener is on the `document`, so clicking the `wrapper` would not trigger the `click` event.

Instead, trigger the event on the `document.body`:

```js
test('test click', () => {
  const eventClick = jest.spyOn(Dashboard.options?.methods || Dashboard.methods, 'eventClick')
  shallowMount(Dashboard)

  document.body.click() 

  expect(eventClick).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-jest-trigger-document-click?file=tests/unit/MyComponent.spec.js)